# Error in UUIDgenerate() : Too many DLL modules. in mlr3 pakcage

Tags: r, dll, mlr3

I using the `mlr3` package for autotuning ML models (mlr3pipelines graph, to be more correct).

It is very hard to reproduce the problem because the error occurs occasionally. The same code sometimes returns an error and sometimes doesn't.

Here is the code snippet

```
learners_l = list(
  ranger = lrn("classif.ranger", predict_type = "prob", id = "ranger"),
  log_reg = lrn("classif.log_reg", predict_type = "prob", id = "log_reg")
)

# create complete grapg
graph = po("removeconstants", ratio = 0.05) %>>%
  po("branch", options = c("nop_prep", "yeojohnson", "pca", "ica"), id = "prep_branch") %>>%
  gunion(list(po("nop", id = "nop_prep"), po("yeojohnson"), po("pca", scale. = TRUE), po("ica"))) %>>%
  po("unbranch", id = "prep_unbranch") %>>%
  learners_l %>>%
  po("classifavg", innum = length(learners))
graph_learner = as_learner(graph)
search_space = ps(
  prep_branch.selection = p_fct(levels = c("nop_prep", "yeojohnson", "pca", "ica")),
  pca.rank. = p_int(2, 6, depends = prep_branch.selection == "pca"),
  ica.n.comp = p_int(2, 6, depends = prep_branch.selection == "ica"),
  yeojohnson.standardize = p_lgl(depends = prep_branch.selection == "yeojohnson"),
  ranger.ranger.mtry.ratio = p_dbl(0.2, 1),
  ranger.ranger.max.depth = p_int(2, 6)
)
at_classif = auto_tuner(
  method = "random_search",
  learner = graph_learner,
  resampling = rsmp("cv", folds = 3),
  measure = msr("classif.acc"),
  search_space = search_space,
  term_evals = 20
)
at_classif$train(task_classif)
```

You can use any task you want.
The error I get is:

```
INFO  [15:05:33.610] [bbotk] Starting to optimize 6 parameter(s) with '<OptimizerRandomSearch>' and '<TerminatorEvals> [n_evals=20, k=0]' 
INFO  [15:05:33.653] [bbotk] Evaluating 1 configuration(s) 
Error in UUIDgenerate() : Too many DLL modules.
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, your code doesn't run for me.

Comment: AFAIK there are some ways to incrase the DLL limit on Windows. If possible, run the code on non-windows machines. To help you here, we need a reproducible example. I haven't heard of any similar issues in the past.

Comment: I have tried to increase DLL modules on windows. I found it can be done via .Renviron file. If I use only one model i t works, but when I use it through mlr3pipeops graph it returns an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a fixed buffer for loading RNG functions in `uuid` which will fail if there are too many DLLs loaded already. A simple work-around is to run

```r
library(uuid)
UUIDgenerate()
```

before other packages which will force the loading of the RNG functions early.

([#12](https://github.com/s-u/uuid/issues/12) now tracks the underlying issue and should be fixed in uuid 1.0-3).